# Insert intermediate level into nested struct array

Tags: matlab, struct, vectorization

I'd like to reorder a struct as follows:

```
%// original struct
s(1).a = rand(10,1);
s(2).a = rand(10,1);
s(1).b = rand(10,1);
s(2).b = rand(10,1);

%// reorder to:
y(1).a = s(1).a;
y(2).a = s(2).a;
y(1).b.c = s(1).b;
y(2).b.c = s(2).b;
```

The following nested loop works:

```
fieldToMove = 'b';
newFieldname = 'c';

fn = fieldnames(s);

for ii = 1:numel(fn)

    for jj = 1:numel(s)
        if strcmp(fn{ii},fieldToMove)
            y(jj).(fn{ii}).(newFieldname) = s(jj).(fn{ii});
        else
            y(jj).(fn{ii}) = s(jj).(fn{ii});
        end
    end
end
```

**But it seems a great overkill to me. Any ideas how to optimize or simplify it?**

---

I experimented a lot with temporary values, removing the original field with `rmfield` and set the new one with `setfield`, but nothing worked so far as always a scalar structur is required. Is there some function I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) and [`setfield`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setfield.html) like so:

```
y = s;
y = arrayfun(@(s) setfield(s, 'b', struct('c', s.b)), y);
```

Another option is to [distribute](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) a modified field `b`:

```
y = s;
temp = num2cell(struct('c', {y.b}));
[y.b] = temp{:};
```

Comment: Both options are very nice! I see I have to learn a lot more about the usage of the setfield function.

Answer (score 3):

Using a combination of `struct` + `num2cell` this can be done

```
y = struct('a', {s.a}, 'b', num2cell(struct('c', {s.b})));
```

Comment: Thanks! It requires the knowledge of `'a'` (and potentially others) though. So I'd rather go with the more generic approach of gnovice.

Answer (score 2):

By assigning `y=s` beforehand, we can skip the if-else statement and also remove one of the for-loops. We can, if we want, add another for-loop to allow `fieldToMove` and `newFieldname` to be cell arrays and thus move multiple fields. Note that if you're only interested in the case where you move a single field, the inner for-loop can be removed.

```
s(1).a = rand(10,1);
s(2).a = rand(10,1);
s(1).b = rand(10,1);
s(2).b = rand(10,1);
s(1).d = rand(10,1);
s(2).d = rand(10,1);

fieldsToMove = {'b','d'};
newFieldnames = {'c','e'};

y = s;
for ii = 1:numel(y)
    for jj = 1:numel(fieldsToMove)
        y(ii).(fieldsToMove{jj}) = struct(newFieldnames{jj},s(ii).(fieldsToMove{jj}));
    end
end
```

Comment: I'm actually a little ashamed of not having thought about this simplification ;) Thanks!